# T-SQL convert xml field to multi column table

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to convert data from a xml field into a table. I have found multiple solutions on this website, but none of them seem to give me exactly what I need.
The xml looks like this:

```
    <table>
  <id>{100}</id>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="cur" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
        <column name="item" value="Item a" type="System.String" />
        <column name="price" value="2.5" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="qty" value="20" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="Key" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="cur" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
        <column name="item" value="Item b" type="System.String" />
        <column name="price" value="30" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="qty" value="30" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="Key" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
  <key>Key</key>
</table>
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
id  key cur  item    price  qty
100 1   EUR  Item a  2.5    20
100 2   EUR  Item b  30     30
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: `nodes` method  of `xml` data type is what you're looking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<table>
  <id>{100}</id>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="cur" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
        <column name="item" value="Item a" type="System.String" />
        <column name="price" value="2.5" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="qty" value="20" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="Key" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="cur" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
        <column name="item" value="Item b" type="System.String" />
        <column name="price" value="30" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="qty" value="30" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="Key" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
  <key>Key</key>
</table>';
SELECT @x.value('(/table/id)[1]','varchar(max)') AS id --are the curly brackets there on purpose?
      ,Rw.value('(columns/column[@name="Key"]/@value)[1]','int') AS [key] 
      ,Rw.value('(columns/column[@name="cur"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS cur 
      ,Rw.value('(columns/column[@name="item"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS item 
      ,Rw.value('(columns/column[@name="price"]/@value)[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS price 
      ,Rw.value('(columns/column[@name="qty"]/@value)[1]','int') AS qty 
 FROM @x.nodes('/table/rows/row') AS A(Rw)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. PS. The curly brackets are put there by the system generating the xml, don't know why.